# Java switch statement is directly going to default

Tags: java

I am inheriting a `Result` class from java class in Result class. In the constructor I am using a Switch but if user enter 1 or another value it not executing and directly going to default.

What is the problem? Any one can explain it to me and also want to utilize FileHandling in  this code as well but how do it not getting the idea?

```
public class Vehicle {
    final public void choose() {
        System.out.println("Thanks!for choosing us");
    }

    public void select() {
        System.out.println("select");
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {

    int Brand;
    int price;
    int noofpeople;

    public void select() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("hello we will help you to choose"
                + "best car for you but for this you have answer some questions.");
        System.out.println("Which Brand you want to choose?");
        System.out.println("press 1 for Toyota");
        System.out.println("Press 2 for Honda");
        System.out.println("Press 3 for BMW");
        Brand = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please enter your price less than or equal to 20lack");
        price = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter your family members");
        noofpeople = s.nextInt();
    }
}

class Toyota extends Car {
    Toyota() {
       System.out.println("You selected toyota");
        if (price == 1000000 && noofpeople == 4) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("passo");
            System.out.println("mooco");
        } else if (price == 200000 && noofpeople == 5) {
            System.out.println("Corolla Grande");
        } else if (price <= 2000000 && noofpeople == 5) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("Corolla gli");
        } else if (price > 2000000 && noofpeople > 5) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");
        }
    }
}

class Honda extends Car {
    Honda() {
        System.out.println("You selected Honda");
        if (price < 1000000 && noofpeople >= 4) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("honda fit");
            System.out.println("honda pure");
        } else if (price == 2000000 && noofpeople >= 5) {
            System.out.println("honda vezel");
        } else if ((price < 2000000 && price > 1000000) && noofpeople == 5) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("Honda civic");
        } else if (price >= 200000 && noofpeople >= 5) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");

        } else if (noofpeople < 4) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");
        }
    }
}

class BMW extends Car {

    BMW() {
        System.out.println("You selected BMW");
        if (price < 1000000 && noofpeople >= 4) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("honda fit");
            System.out.println("honda pure");
        } else if (price == 2000000 && noofpeople >= 5) {
            System.out.println("honda vezel");
        } else if ((price < 2000000 && price > 1000000) && noofpeople == 5) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("Honda civic");
        } else if (price >= 200000 && noofpeople >= 5) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");
        } else if (noofpeople < 4) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");
        }
    }
}

class Result extends Car {
    Result() {
        Car c = new Car();
        c.choose();
        c.select();
        switch (Brand) {
            case 1:
                Toyota a = new Toyota();
                break;
            case 2:
                Honda h = new Honda();
                break;
            default:
                BMW n = new BMW();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also consider that those declarations only exist inside the `switch` statement.

Comment: Just for clarification: In the switch statement, is "Brand" an int value?

Comment: Nevermind :P it is

Comment: Debugger. Use it.

Comment: Indentation. Apply it.

Comment: 1) Use proper formatting to make your code readable. Your code appears to be indented randomly indicating you probably use a combination of spaces and tabs. Use one or the other and not both. 2) Use white spaces to make statements readable. **else if((price<2000000&&price>1000000)&&noofpeople==5)** add a space between each variable/operand. 3) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few wrong concepts in your code. Here are some of them:

- Your class `Result` should not extends `Car`. It is not a car.
- Your class `Result` mixes properties of the Car with the logic to choose the car

  - Leave the properties of the Car inside the car class itself.
- The switch is part of your input, don't let it inside your model.
- Use camel standard for coding, more details [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)
- I don't see why you use Car and Vehicle together.
- For Price, `int` is not the best option in a production code environment. One suggestion, as you are learning, is using `BigDecimal`.

What I would do:

- Remove the class Result
- Let the values inside the Car object
- The selection is part of you flow not your model

Here your code modified:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("hello we will help you to choose"
                + "best car for you but for this you have answer some questions.");
        System.out.println("Which Brand you want to choose?");
        System.out.println("press 1 for Toyota");
        System.out.println("Press 2 for Honda");
        System.out.println("Press 3 for BMW");
        int brand = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter your price less than or equal to 20lack");
        int price = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("please enter your family members");
        int numberOfPeople = s.nextInt();

        switch (brand) {
            case 1:
                Car toyota = new Toyota(price, numberOfPeople);
                toyota.select();
                break;
            case 2:
                Car honda = new Honda(price, numberOfPeople);
                honda.select();
                break;
            default:
                Car bmw = new BMW(price, numberOfPeople);
                bmw.select();
                break;
        }

    }
}

abstract class Car {
    int price;
    int numberOfPeople;

    public Car(int price, int numberOfPeople) {
        this.price = price;
        this.numberOfPeople = numberOfPeople;
    }

    public abstract void select();

}

class Toyota extends Car {
    public Toyota(int price, int numberOfPeople) {
        super(price, numberOfPeople);
    }

    @Override
    public void select() {
        System.out.println("You selected toyota");
        if (price == 1000000 && numberOfPeople == 4) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("passo");
            System.out.println("mooco");
        } else if (price == 200000 && numberOfPeople == 5) {
            System.out.println("Corolla Grande");
        } else if (price <= 2000000 && numberOfPeople == 5) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("Corolla gli");
        } else if (price > 2000000 && numberOfPeople > 5) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");
        }
    }
}

class Honda extends Car {
    public Honda(int price, int numberOfPeople) {
        super(price, numberOfPeople);
    }

    @Override
    public void select() {
        System.out.println("You selected Honda");
        if (price < 1000000 && numberOfPeople >= 4) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("honda fit");
            System.out.println("honda pure");
        } else if (price == 2000000 && numberOfPeople >= 5) {
            System.out.println("honda vezel");
        } else if ((price < 2000000 && price > 1000000) && numberOfPeople == 5) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("Honda civic");
        } else if (price >= 200000 && numberOfPeople >= 5) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");

        } else if (numberOfPeople < 4) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");
        }
    }
}

class BMW extends Car {
    public BMW(int price, int numberOfPeople) {
        super(price, numberOfPeople);
    }

    public void select() {
        System.out.println("You selected BMW");
        if (price < 1000000 && numberOfPeople >= 4) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("honda fit");
            System.out.println("honda pure");
        } else if (price == 2000000 && numberOfPeople >= 5) {
            System.out.println("honda vezel");
        } else if ((price < 2000000 && price > 1000000) && numberOfPeople == 5) {
            System.out.println("The Best Cars for you are:");
            System.out.println("Honda civic");
        } else if (price >= 200000 && numberOfPeople >= 5) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");
        } else if (numberOfPeople < 4) {
            System.out.println("No car for found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer and the next step would be to refactor those horrible `select()` methods

Comment: Thanks for your Precious suggestions it was great answer from which I learned a lot as I am in Learning Phase so sorry for some big flaws in the Program and please give me suggestion to improve my programming as well @Patrick Santana